# Why is TYPO3 Solr relation language not working?

Tags: solr, typo3, typo3-9.x

I'm indexing records on a page with 5 languages. There I have a couple of properties which are defined as mm relations through TCA, for example that one

```
'working_hours' => [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:jobads/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_jobads_domain_model_jobad.working_hours',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_jobads_domain_model_workinghours',
        'MM' => 'tx_jobads_jobad_workinghours_mm',
        'size' => 10,
        'autoSizeMax' => 30,
        'maxitems' => 9999,
        'multiple' => 0,
        'fieldControl' => [
            'editPopup' => [
                'disabled' => false,
            ],
            'addRecord' => [
                'disabled' => false,
            ],
            'listModule' => [
                'disabled' => true,
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

In my index TypoScript is a field defined as SOLR_RELATION

```
workingHours_stringM = SOLR_RELATION
workingHours_stringM {
    localField = working_hours
    foreignLabelField = title
    multiValue = 1
}
```

The problem is that for all languages only the german translation is indexed for that field.

I tried different `sys_language_mode` settings, but didn't helped either. Anyone an idea?

TYPO3 Version 9.5.5
Solr Version is 9.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out. I still need the definition [globalVar = GP:L = 1]…[..] for every language in v9.x.x then it works like expected